# What is the best way to create an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I understand that in Javascript, I can create an object like this:

```
var cup = {};
```

Furthermore, I can set properties like this:

```
cup.color = 'Blue';
cup.size = 'Large';
cup.type = 'Mug';
```

Can I create an array of cups? For example:

```
cup[0].color = 'Blue';
cup[1].size = 'Large';
cup[2].type = 'Mug';
```

Comment: This would be an array of objects. `var cups = [{color:'Blue',size:'Large',type:'Mug'},{color:'Red',size:'Small',type:'Glass'}]`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Creating an array is as simple as this:

```
var cups = [];
```

You can create a populated array like this:

```
var cups = [
    {
        color:'Blue'
    },
    {
        color:'Green'
    }
];
```

You can add more items to the array like this:

```
cups.push({
    color:"Red"
});
```

[MDN array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "W3" is very misleading, please reference either the language specification or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array) for examples and support.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put.

```
cup[0].color = 'Blue';
cup[1].size = 'Large';
cup[2].type = 'Mug';
```

In JS this would result into as a nested object, an object containing other objects

```
cup = {
    0: {
       color: 'Blue'
    },
    1: {
       size: 'Large'
    },
    2: {
       color: 'Mug'
    }
}
```

if you want to create array of objects you can do.. as @wachkozaco said.

```
var cup = [{color:'Blue',size:'Large',type:'Mug'},{color:'Red',size:'S‌​mall',type:'Cup'}]
```

or more intuitively

```
var cup = [];
var obj = {color: 'Red', size: 'small', type: 'Cup'};
cup[0] = obj; // also cup.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

> The array should be like this...

```
var cup = [];
```

---

> After we putting properties to the array, it will be like this

```
[
  {
    "color": "blue",
    "size": "large",
    "type": "mug"
  }
]
```

---

> And you can put properties like this..

```js
var cup = [];

cup.push({

   color : 'blue',
   size : 'large',
   type : 'mug'

})

console.log(cup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is typically what I see:

```
var arr = []
for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
    arr[n] = {color: null, size: null, type: null}
}
```

But usually a pattern like this isn't necessary and you should reconsider the problem your trying to solve.